# Open CV Optical Flow Assertion Failed Error

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run Lucas Kanade code from https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html on google colab.

I get this error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:1250: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function 'calc'

I tried converting vector received from goodFeaturesToTrack to float32, but it didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: Link is - https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html

Comment: Error is in line- p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

Comment: don't use that site. it's outdated and not official. all the information is to be found on https://docs.opencv.org/ try that, and then edit your question